# What does "lose the power to shock" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The killing of Qassem Suleimani by an American drone on January 3rd threatened to bring the United States and Iran closer to war than at any time since the hostage crisis in 1979. In a part of the world that **has lost the power to shock**, the audacious killing of Iran’s most important general, ordered by President Donald Trump, sent Iran reeling. (https://www.economist.com/leaders/2020/01/09/donald-trump-wants-to-curb-iran-has-he-gone-about-it-the-right-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they really mean is 'in a part of the world *where such news* has lost the power to shock'. There has been conflict in the Middle East for so long that hearing of violent incidents there has become normal.